# How to add icone in 'svg' format to SweetAlert for Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I try to add the `image.svg` icon to `imageUrl` in alert 'swal'. It is located in the same folder as the file 'index.js'. The icon is not added

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y5v8tc?file=index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import swal from 'sweetalert';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  show = () => {
    console.log('show')
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     swal({
      title: 'dddddd', 
      text: 'dddddddd',
      icon: "info",
      buttons: true,
      showCancelButton: false,
      imageUrl: './image.svg',
      buttons: {
        confirm : {text: 'button'}
      },
      confirmButtonClass: "btn-info",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    })
    .then((isConfirm) => {
      if (isConfirm) {
        this.show();
      }
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: move icon to Public folder

Comment: @Raphael It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to load the icon first:

```
import Icon from './image.svg';
```

and later on reuse it removing icon from sweet alert:

```
componentDidMount() {
...
icon: {Icon},
....
}
```

[Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zgxfkp?embed=1&file=index.js) attached.

Comment: not working at all